# Is it possible to calculate z-score given the probability using a casio calculator?

Tags: normal-distribution, calculator

I have a casio fx-991EX CLASSWIZ calculator and I would like to know if it is possible to calculate the z-score knowing the probability. Every source I found explains the inverse (calculating probability given z-score).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The manual says yes. https://support.casio.com/en/manual/004/fx-570_991EX_EN.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask, to which part of the manual are you referring too?

Comment: Page 31, distribution calculations. Should be clear when you open the file.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Please be more specific, so that I do not waste more of your time. Are you referring to the inverse normal function? If that is so, as far as I did not miss anything while experimenting with it, the calculator is only able to find X given the mean, standard deviation and probability. I do not want that; I want the calculator to give me the whole z-score given the probability. Those two are different because it might be the case that I know X, but am trying to find e.g. the mean.

Comment: Those are the same - if you want the z-score, set the mean equal to zero and the standard deviation equal to 1.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Mindblowing! Thank you a lot!